# How to color path elements in SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg, background-color, fill

A couple of days ago I received an SVG from some designers, and I am to implement it with some color alterations and the typical hover effects and such, */edit:* but the main thing for now is to just be able to control the background color */edit/*.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div>
  <svg class="drawelements" viewBox="50 200 550 360">
    <polygon fill="red" points="312.200 265.600, 312.200 332.300, 265.600 332.300, 265.600 265.600, 312.200 265.600, 312.700 265.100, 265.100 265.100, 265.100 332.800, 312.700 332.800, 312.700 265.100, 312.700 265.100"></polygon>
    <path class="st0" d="M369 265.6v66.7h-46.6v-66.7H369M369.5 265.1h-47.6v67.7h47.6V265.1L369.5 265.1z"></path>
    <path class="st0" d="M425.7 265.6v66.7h-46.6v-66.7H425.7M426.2 265.1h-47.6v67.7h47.6V265.1L426.2 265.1z"></path>
    <path class="st0" d="M480.6 265.6v66.7H434v-66.7H480.6M481.1 265.1h-47.6v67.7h47.6V265.1L481.1 265.1z"></path>
    <path class="st0" d="M537.3 265.6v66.7h-46.6v-66.7H537.3M537.8 265.1h-47.6v67.7h47.6V265.1L537.8 265.1z"></path>
    <path class="st0" d="M255.5 265.6v66.7H209v-66.7H255.5M256 265.1h-47.6v67.7H256V265.1L256 265.1z"></path>
    <path class="st0" d="M537.3 207.3v49.4H209v-49.4H537.3M537.8 206.8H208.5v50.4h329.3V206.8L537.8 206.8z"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle of how it looks: [fiddle](http://codepen.io/djdifee/pen/BQyqzv)

I wanted to test with a polygon at the top, just to make sure that it was not the path element that was working against me.

Regular styling with CSS doesn't work, and hard coded styling within each element does not work. Is it because I need to use something else than *background-color* or *fill*?

If you look at the fiddle, please don't mind the viewBox. The actual svg contains many more elements which I removed for this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that you had used was not wrong. Generally, the way to fill a SVG box or a shape with color is to make use of the `fill` property but the problem was with the `path` elements.

In the code that is provided in question, the path elements are created in such a way that the leave a gap at the center of the shape. The  shape is actually more like a ***frame*** than a solid board and that is the reason that applying a `fill` doesn't look like it is applying a background color to the shape.

The `d` attribute of the `path` element has the coordinates and defines how the shape is drawn - below is an explanation of how it can be interpreted:

- `M369 265.6` - **m**oves the imaginary pen to the coordinate (369,265.6)
- `v66.7` - draws a **v**ertical line to a point which is below the previous point by a distance of 66.7 units
- `h-46.6` - draws a **h**orizontal line to a point which is to the left of the previous point (the end-point of the vertical line) by a distance of 46.6 units (left because the value is negative)
- `v-66.7` - draws a **v**ertical line to a point which is above the previous point by a distance of 66.7 units
- `H369` - draws a **H**orizontal line to the point that represents 369 units in the X-axis (its not relative to the previous point in this case because the alphabet is upper-case).

Now the above alone would produce a rectangle. You can then apply a `stroke` (equivalent to border) or a `fill` (equivalent to background color) to it. But in your case, the `d` attribute also had the below commands + parameters which create an **inner box**.

```
M369.5 265.1h-47.6v67.7h47.6V265.1L369.5 265.1z
```

So, the final shape is something like the below:

[image]

When you apply a `fill` here to the shape, you'd see only the ***orange colored area*** and that's why it just looks like a border instead of a fill.

[This MDN tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) has more information about the SVG `path` element and its commands.

---

I have no idea why the designer had used such an approach but in my opinion this is both weird and wrong. If the need was to just have an outline, the designer must have just used the `stroke` property of the `path` rather than create an inner box and give it a `fill`.

Anyway the fix for your case would be to just do away with everything starting from the second `M` of the `d` attribute of all `path` elements and then just apply a `fill` to them. For the `polygon` element also the second set of coordinates can be removed like in the below snippet:

```css
.st0 {
  fill: #AAA;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg class="drawelements" viewBox="50 200 550 360">
    <polygon fill="red" points="312.200 265.600, 312.200 332.300, 265.600 332.300, 265.600 265.600, 312.200 265.600"></polygon>
    <path class="st0" d="M369 265.6v66.7h-46.6v-66.7H369z"></path>
    <path class="st0" d="M425.7 265.6v66.7h-46.6v-66.7H425.7z"></path>
    <path class="st0" d="M480.6 265.6v66.7H434v-66.7H480.6z"></path>
    <path class="st0" d="M537.3 265.6v66.7h-46.6v-66.7H537.3z"></path>
    <path class="st0" d="M255.5 265.6v66.7H209v-66.7H255.5z"></path>
    <path class="st0" d="M537.3 207.3v49.4H209v-49.4H537.3z"></path>
    <path class="st0" d="M537.3 341.1v42.3H209v-42.3H537.3z"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

**Note:**

- By default there would be a black fill if no `fill` is specified either through attribute or CSS. You can overcome it by specifying the required color as fill (or) by setting it to transparent/none.
- The `fill` property ***specified in CSS will take priority*** over the `fill` attribute specified in the SVG element. This is as per spec.

Comment: This is great, thanks again! I will check out that MDN tutorial, as I'm suspecting I will get to do more work with SVG in the future.

Comment: You're most welcome @KristofferLund. Happy that I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

CSS appears to override the path's **fill** attribute,

you can apply CSS to SVG, but you need to match the element, just as when styling HTML.  If you just want to apply it to all SVG paths, you could use, for example:

```
​path {
    fill: blue;
}​
```

**Update Your Css**

```
div {
  fill: red;
}

svg {
  fill: blue;
}

// This does not work
.st0 {
  fill: red;
}
```

**Snippet Example Below**

```css
div {
  fill: red;
}

svg {
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
<svg class="drawelements" viewBox="50 200 550 360">
<polygon fill="red" points="312.200 265.600, 312.200 332.300, 265.600 332.300, 265.600 265.600, 312.200 265.600, 312.700 265.100, 265.100 265.100, 265.100 332.800, 312.700 332.800, 312.700 265.100, 312.700 265.100"></polygon>
<path class="st0" d="M369 265.6v66.7h-46.6v-66.7H369M369.5 265.1h-47.6v67.7h47.6V265.1L369.5 265.1z"></path>
<path class="st0" d="M425.7 265.6v66.7h-46.6v-66.7H425.7M426.2 265.1h-47.6v67.7h47.6V265.1L426.2 265.1z"></path>
<path class="st0" d="M480.6 265.6v66.7H434v-66.7H480.6M481.1 265.1h-47.6v67.7h47.6V265.1L481.1 265.1z"></path>
<path class="st0" d="M537.3 265.6v66.7h-46.6v-66.7H537.3M537.8 265.1h-47.6v67.7h47.6V265.1L537.8 265.1z"></path>
<path class="st0" d="M255.5 265.6v66.7H209v-66.7H255.5M256 265.1h-47.6v67.7H256V265.1L256 265.1z"></path>
<path class="st0" d="M537.3 207.3v49.4H209v-49.4H537.3M537.8 206.8H208.5v50.4h329.3V206.8L537.8 206.8z"></path>
<path class="st0" d="M537.3 341.1v42.3H209v-42.3H537.3M537.8 340.6H208.5v43.3h329.3V340.6L537.8 340.6z"></path>

</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I got the fill to work, but for some reason that only applies color in the same form as an outline. Can this be because the SVG I got from the designer is only made out of outlines, and not shapes, like they look like?

Comment: @KristofferLund: Yes, the `path` is actually designed in such a way that it produces a .5 thick line and so the `fill` looks like a `stroke` instead. I don't know why your designer has done it this way instead of using `stroke` but I find it very weird and wrong. In all your `path` elements, if you remove the things from the second `M` till the end in the `d` attribute's value then you'd be able to see the fill working properly.

Comment: @KristofferLund: You're welcome. Do you want me to post it as a separate answer to accept (or) are you going to accept Sumit's answer. Either is fine with me.

Comment: @Harry If it's no problem for you, please post it as a separate answer and I will accept it :)

Comment: Ok @KristofferLund I'll post as an answer with a bit more details so that you can understand more clearly :)